# How to display a user's full name on crystal reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I want to display the full name of the user logged in on the system on the crystal reports. I was only able to display the user's username. Here's the code:

```
        ParameterFields myParamFields = new ParameterFields();
        ParameterField myParamTitle1 = new ParameterField();
        ParameterDiscreteValue pdvParamTitle1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        myParamTitle1.ParameterFieldName = "Username";

        pdvParamTitle1.Value = "stcInv.Username";

        myParamTitle1.CurrentValues.Add(pdvParamTitle1);

        myParamFields.Add(myParamTitle1);

        crvUserIndividual.ParameterFieldInfo = myParamFields;
```

Comment: Where are you getting the full name of the user?

Comment: @user1426542 I have a table Users on my database.

Comment: Is the full name will be a parameter passed to the report or you just want to display the full name in the report? What kind of database and how is your report connected to db?

Comment: @user1426542 I just want to display the full name of the user currently logged in on the system. And the database is connected through OLEDB (ADO). (I'm new to C# and Crystal Reports so forgive me if I'm a little unsure on how to answer your questions.)

Comment: Does your database includes the username? Can you do a query and grab the full name based on the username?

Comment: @user1426542 Yes. The database includes a username column. But it doesn't include a Full name column. It has First, MI and Last names column though.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you don't have the **Full Name** in the database therefore you can't display it in the Crystal Reports.

There're few options that you can display the Full Name of the currently logged in user.

1. Create a view in your database and merge the FirstName + ' '+ LastName as FullName.

Assuming it's a sql:

```
select username, firstName, lastName, MI, firstname + ' ' + lastName as FullName from sometable
```

Save it as ex. sometable_v

Now you have a FullName to use in the Crystal Reports.

In the back end of your C# code, get the username of the person who is logged in:

```
string username = Environment.UserName;
```

The namespace is

```
using system;
```

Once you have a username you can do a sql query in c# from the above view to get the fullName based on the username:

Once you have the full Name you can then pass it to your Crystal Reports.

There're much easier ways to display data in Crystal Report from database. But unfortunately, we don't really know what you're trying to accomplish.

First, you need to understand the basics of Crystal Reports before you start integrating it with different applications.